# Pegar cores da imagem

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, imagem

Há uma possibilidade (com plugins ou não) de pegar as **[principais] cores** ou as **cores predominantes**, parecido com o Adobe Kuler, da imagem?

**Exemplo**

Tenho essa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E queria pegar as principais cores dela, que seria **Azul**

Comment: Fazer no braço não é algo trivial, você deveria dar uma olhada neste plugin Javascript: [**```Color Thief```**](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/)

Comment: Para fazer isso "na munheca" você teria que ler todos os pixels da imagem, capturar o código `RGB` ou `Hex` (Potato ou potato IMO), alimentar um array e depois selecionar as maiores ocorrências. Nada trivial. Vale como estudo acadêmico, naturalmente. Há um bom estudo de caso (em C#, não sei da possibilidade de realizar em PHP) aqui: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/color-detecting-in-an-image-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: A maioria das bibliotecas de tratamento de imagem para PHP (Cairo, GD, Exif, GMagix, Imagemagick) possui uma função para pegar a cor de um único pixel. Você pode passar uma imagem como *input* e aí percorrer por todos os seus pixels para montar uma matriz de cores. Depois disso, seria só questão de montar uma tabela de frequência para buscar a(s) cor(es) mais predominante(s) na imagem.

Comment: @LeonardoDiego precisa ser em JS?

Comment: @AndreCalil Não precisa!

Comment: @LeonardoDiego Uma solução em `C#` te interessa? :)

Comment: @AndreCalil não :\

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O seguinte código monta um objeto contendo o histograma e recupera a cor mais comum usando um elemento `canvas` invisível:

```js
//carrega uma imagem
var img = new Image();
img.src = ...

//cria um canvas invisível
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//desenha a imagem no canvas
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

//recupera vetor de cores
var map = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;

//monta histograma
var hex, r,g,b; //,alpha;
var histograma = {};
for (var i = 0, len = map.length; i < len; i += 4) {

    //recupera componentes de um ponto
    r = arredonda(map[i]);
    g = arredonda(map[i+1]);
    b = arredonda(map[i+2]);
    //alpha = map[i+2]; //ignora canal alpha

    //valor em hexadecimal
    hex = rgbToHex(r, g, b);

    //adiciona no histograma ou incrementa se já existir
    if (histograma[hex] === undefined) {
        histograma[hex] = 1;
    } else {
        histograma[hex]++;
    }
}

//recupera cor mais comum
var corMaisComum = null;
var frequenciaCorMaisComum = 0;
for (var cor in histograma) {
    if (frequenciaCorMaisComum < histograma[cor]) {
        corMaisComum = cor;
        frequenciaCorMaisComum = histograma[cor];
    }
}

console.log(corMaisComum);
```

O histograma nada mais é do que um tipo de mapa onde a chave é a cor em notação hexadecimal e o valor é a frequência com que a mesma ocorre na imagem.

Nesse algoritmo, usei a função `arredonda` ao recuperar a cor para arredondá-la para o múltiplo de 5 mais próximo. Dessa forma, pequenas variações na cor não irão atrapalhar o resultado final.

Note que com p histograma não somente podemos obter a cor mais comum, mas também as primeiras `N` cores mais comuns. Para isso teríamos apenas que criar um vetor com as cores ordenado pela frequência.

O código anterior pode ser visto *executanto* no site [jsdo.it](http://jsdo.it/utluiz/x3pO), mas postarei o mesmo completo, caso se torne inacessível um dia:

```js
//"arredonda" o número para o múltiplo de 5 mais próximo
//isso adiciona uma certa tolerância para os tons próximos
function arredonda(v) {
    return 5 * (Math.round(v / 5));
}

function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

//carrega uma imagem
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://jsrun.it/assets/8/O/3/U/8O3Ux.jpg';
img.onload = function() {

    $(document.body).append(img);

    //cria um canvas invisível
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    //desenha a imagem no canvas
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    //recupera vetor de cores
    var map = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;

    var hex, r,g,b; //,alpha;
    var histograma = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = map.length; i < len; i += 4) {

        //recupera componentes de um ponto
        r = arredonda(map[i]);
        g = arredonda(map[i+1]);
        b = arredonda(map[i+2]);
        //alpha = map[i+2]; //ignora canal alpha

        //valor em hexadecimal
        hex = rgbToHex(r, g, b);

        //adiciona no histograma ou incrementa se já existir
        if (histograma[hex] === undefined) {
            histograma[hex] = 1;
        } else {
            histograma[hex]++;
        }
    }

    //recupera cor mais comum
    var corMaisComum = null;
    var frequenciaCorMaisComum = 0;
    for (var cor in histograma) {
        if (frequenciaCorMaisComum < histograma[cor]) {
            corMaisComum = cor;
            frequenciaCorMaisComum = histograma[cor];
        }
    }

    console.log(corMaisComum);

    //adiciona um div como exemplo
    $(document.body).append(
        $('<div>').css({
            'background-color': corMaisComum,
            'width': '200px',
            'height': '200px',
            'border': '1px solid #000'
        })
    );

};
```

O resultado visual fica como na imagem abaixo:

[image: resultado com a cor retornada]

Comment: No meu entendimento, essa é a resposta que julgo ser correta :)

Comment: :O foi você que fez cara?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Sim, mas não é muito diferente da sua resposta, a não ser que ao invés de fazer a média eu conto a quantidade de vezes que uma cor aparece.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode utilizar da tecnologia *Canvas* que é contida nos navegadores que suportam HTML5(atualmente a maioria), e com ele você pode fazer uma função JavaScript que recebe como parâmetro sua imagem e verifica de 5 em 5 pixels qual a determinada cor, e verifica na imagem inteira, e então a cor predominante é setada via *R,G,B*(red,green,blue) no fundo de sua página.

HTML Exemplar seria:

```html
<span> Background é setado para a cor predominante desta imagem: </span>
<img id="i" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYI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"/>
```

**Obs:** Converti sua imagem em [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) :)

E a função que faz a **mágica** seria esta:

```js
    var rgb = getAverageRGB(document.getElementById('i'));
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';

function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {

    var blockSize = 5, //checa a cor à cada 5 pixels
        defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // para browsers com incompatibilidade
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data, width, height,
        i = -4,
        length,
        rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
        count = 0; //zera o contador

    if (!context) {
        return defaultRGB;
    }

    height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
    width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

    context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0); //desenha a imagem cria o canvas

    try {
        data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    } catch(e) {
        /* gera um erro de segurança, se a imagem for de dominio diferente */alert('x');
        return defaultRGB;//retorna  a cor padrão
    }

    length = data.data.length; //tamanho do array dos dados da imagem

    while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
        ++count; //incrementa o contador previamente zerado
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
    }

    // ~~ usado para arrendondar valores para baixo
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);

    return rgb;

}
```

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle com sua imagem.](http://jsfiddle.net/D5hEG/1/)

## Importante:

A função não é de minha autoria, aqui está a **[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541680/2319589)** da resposta no SOEN.

Comment: Pelo resultado que você postou, acho que a função pega a cor média, e não a predominante, certo?

Comment: Acha porque? Explique.

Comment: Pra converter a imagem em base64 em php seria usando a função "base64_encode", certo?

Comment: Sim, a `base64_encode` para converter e a `base64_decode` para desconverter :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto Primeiro você soma todos os valores de `r`, `g` e `b` para depois dividir cada um deles pela contagem de pixels. Isso é a média. O usuário que postou a pergunta quer a cor mais predominante, que dentro de uma tabela de frequências seria a cor que possui a maior contagem. O problema é se a imagem em questão for, por exemplo, um JPEG de baixa qualidade, onde pode haver diversas cores próximas mas nenhuma muito predominante (digamos, maior do que 20%). Agora para imagens do tipo GIF ou PNG, não haveria problema.

Comment: Mas a média não seria mais provável que seja a cor predominante?? faça testes se ficar interessado, com outras imagens, se você obter resultados me avise podemos melhorar esta função juntos :)

Comment: Então, no meu entendimento a cor predominante é aquela que está com maior frequência. Pode ser que para o autor, o conceito seja esse que você explicou. Primeiro é interessante sabermos o que ele quer para, então, propormos uma alteração no algoritmo ;)

Comment: Meu caro @LeonardoDiego você quer a cor que aparece com maior frequência na imagem? ou a média das cores presentes na imagem? dependendo desta resposta iremos alterar o algoritmo :)